# PHP regular expression using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Let's say I have the string: `"Test [[1294]] example"`

How could I do a `preg_replace()` that would extract the number from the double brackets?

What is the (greedy) expression for getting that number? -it'll always be a integer within double brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You might want to check out a tutorial.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

If you want to "extract" the number, there is no need for `preg_replace`. Use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` (if there are multiple occurrences) instead:

```
preg_match('/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/', $input, $matches);
$integer = $matches[1];
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/', $input, $matches);
$integerArray = $matches[1];
```

If instead of "extract" you actually meant something like "how can I `preg_replace` this term and use the extracted integer number", you can use the same regular expression and refer to the captured integer, using `$1`:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/', 'Found this integer -> $1 <-', $input);
```

Which would result in:

```
Test Found this integer -> 1294 <- example
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get that preg_replace to be non-greedy? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `preg_match()`, not `preg_replace()`:

```
$subject = 'Test [[1294]] example';
preg_match('/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/', $subject, $match);
echo $match[1];
```